# Dynamically position two divs relative to one another

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

I have two divs: divA and divB. I want to position divB below divA at all times using CSS/Sass. Even if divA moves around divB should be positioned below divA. The divs should appear at the same place as the page scrolls so they can't be positioned static. The two divs cannot have the same parent div as divB is part of another div defined in material library.

So the HTML structure is like this:

```
<divA></divA>
<md-tab-group> <!-- uneditable code by user below this -->
<divB></divB>
<divC></divC>
</md-tab-group>
```

CSS:

```
#divA {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 700;
  transition: transform 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

#divB {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 600;
  background-color: white;
  transform: translateY(64px);
  transition: transform 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.navdown {
  transform: translateY(-64px);
}
```

I append the class `navdown` to divA when the user scrolls down for some distance. I want the divB to be still placed below divA without adding any script to divB as I am unable to do so in a proper way in Angular 2.

Comment: "I want to position divB below divA at all times" Does this imply divA will move? Can you show the code that will make it move?

Comment: Since they can't share a parent, this has to be solved with script as there is no CSS/Sass that will, and I suggest you use the same script that is going to move the A. If you need help with that, post a minimal working code snippet showing how this will work

Comment: @styfle Yes, the divA moves and I want to move divB along with it. But I can't add a script that affects the divB. I am editing the question to include the required code.